# Is there a word for it has a use, but to you it has no use?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, the point of pubic hair is to trap pheromones and be a lubricant for sex. In my opinion, it's not very useful. Is there a word to describe this situation. Where it has a use but the user believes that its use is unnecessary and the user would be better off without it, making it essentially useless?

Comment: _Expendable_  or _Redundant_ perhaps.

Comment: *Obsolete* perchance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use "superfluous" which is defined by [vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/superfluous) as

> When something is so unnecessary that it could easily be done away
>   with

And the same in [oxforddictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/superfluous)